# ReactJS NodeJs after delete method everything stop working

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

Hello i was worked on crud app everything is worked fine but when i create delete route i cannot post data to server i get empty string and error cannot get  if i follow get link i try to comment all delete methods but still no one is working even toast are stopped working works only navigate buttons ..

Server

```
index.js

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "crud_contact",
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/api/get", function(req,res){
  console.log('Hello');
  db.query('SELECT * FROM contact_db', function (error, result) {
    res.send(result);
  });
});

app.post("/api/post", (req, res) => {
  const {name, email, contact} = req.body;
  const sqlInsert =
   `INSERT INTO contact_db (name,email, contact)
   VALUES (?, ?, ?)`;
   db.query(sqlInsert, [name, email, contact], (error,result) => {
    res.send(result);
    if(error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
   });
  })

 // app.delete("/api/remove/:id", (req, res) => {
//    const {id} = req.params;
 //   const sqlRemove =
 //    `DElETE FROM contact_db WHERE id = ?`;
 //    db.query(sqlRemove, id , (error,result) => {
  //     if(error) {
  //       console.log(error);
 //      }
 //    });
 //   })
//

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // app.listen(5000, () => {
  //  con.connect(function(err) {
  //    if (err) throw err;
  //    console.log("Connected!");
  //   var sql = `INSERT INTO contact_db(name,email, contact)
  //   VALUES('popas','berazumis@gmail.com',8585858)`;
  //    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  //     if (err) throw err;
  //       console.log("record inserted");
  //     });
  //    });
  //  });
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Listening port 5000");
});
```

Client

Add edit user

```
AddEdit.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./AddEdit.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const initiaState = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  contact: "",
};

const AddEdit = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initiaState);

  const { name, email, contact } = state;

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!name || !email || !contact) {
      toast.error("Please fill all labels below");
    } else {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/api/post", {
          name,
          email,
          contact
        })
        .then(() => {
          setState({ name: "", email: "", contact: "" });
        })
        .catch((err) => toast.error(err.response.data));
      setTimeout(() => navigate.push("/"), 500);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
      <form
        style={{
          margin: "auto",
          padding: "15px",
          maxWidth: "400px",
          alignContent: "cener",
        }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          name="name"
          placeholder="Type Name..."
          value={name}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Type Email..."
          value={email}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="contact">Contact</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="contact"
          name="contact"
          placeholder="Type contact number"
          value={contact}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <Link to="/">
          <input type="submit" value="save" />

          <input type="button" value="Go Back" />
        </Link>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddEdit;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Home.css";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import axios from "axios";

const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/get");
    setData(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  /* const deleteContact = (id) => {
    if(window.confirm("Are you sure that you wanna delete contact")) {
      axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/remove/${id}`);
      toast.success("Contact Deleted Successfully");
      setTimeout(() => loadData(), 500);
    }
  }
  */

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "150px" }}>
    <Link to="addContact">
      <button className="btn btn-contact">Add contact</button>
      </Link>
      <table className="styled-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>No.</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Name</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Email</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Contact</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.email}</td>
                <td>{item.contact}</td>
                <td>
                  <Link to={`/update/${item.id}`}>
                    <button className="btn btn-edit" >Edit</button>
                  </Link>
                  <button className="btn btn-delete" /*onClick={() => deleteContact}*/ >Delete</button>
                  <Link to={`/view/${item.id}`}>
                    <button className="btn btn-view">View</button>
                  </Link>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a app.delete route, you no longer use POST method on your client side, you need to use the DELETE method.

Client Side Example

```
const res = await axios.delete('https://example.com/delete', { data: { answer: 42 } });
```

Server Side Example

```
app.delete('/delete', async(req, res,next) => {
      console.log('req.body', req.body) 
      //prints { data: { answer: 42 } }

})
```

Comment: so you mean i need to remove post method when i add delete method ? Now i try to add delete method like you said but mine POST method is giving me emty string to data , i tryed before to remove my delete method becouse when i create a delete method mine data is stop working even if i remove that delete my data dont response like before

Comment: You do not need to delete your post request. I meant when you post, you use post, when you delete, you use delete. inspect your post/delete request, did the body get send over to your backend?